# find repeated values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Given this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => aaa
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => bbb
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => aaa
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => ccc
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => aaa
        )        
)
```

How can I check if a value for a specific key is used more than once and return the key?

For example, I want to know which keys have the repeated "id" sub key. In this case id = 3 appears more than once so the result would be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
)
```

Notice that index 0 is not included because it's not actually repeated since is the first to appear.

Comment: Create a second array.  Loop through the first.  For each, check if the `id` is in the second array.  If it is not, add it.  If it is, echo the index of the current item (or add that index to a 3rd array to create the array you're showing)

Comment: What if id 1 was also repeated, what would the result look like?  How would you differentiate between 1 and 3?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Then it's repeated index would be added to the final result

Comment: So from your example array, if array [1] was id 1 and array [3] was id 1 the result would just be `2,3,4`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver That's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to **find** the repeated values, rather than eliminate them, you could achieve this by combining [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)  [array_diff_uassoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-uassoc.php) and [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to return an array of the repeated values while maintaining the indexes:

```
$ids = array_column($originalArray, 'id');
$uniqueIds = array_unique($ids);
$repeatedValuesArray = array_diff_uassoc($ids, $uniqueIds, "key_compare_func");
```

Comment: @MatíasCánepa the edit should work, but an even simpler version would be `array_diff_assoc($ids, $uniqueIds);`  The answer just provides an additional index check.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate your array and add the id of each item to an array. If you encounter an id that's already in the array, add its key to an array of duplicates.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    if (isset($ids[$item['id']])) {
        $duplicates[] = $key;
    } else {
        $ids[$item['id']] = true;
    }
}
```

I prefer to use the unique attribute (`id` in the case) as the key (like `$ids[$item['id']]`) instead of the value so it can be looked up with `isset` rather than `in_array`.

Comment: i don't why you are using isset($ids[$item['id']]

Comment: @whoami to check if the id of the current item has already been added to the array of ids, meaning the current item is a duplicate.

Comment: what a brilliant answer, i am daily working on arrays, still panic on array, is nice way to learn array